# How to paint weight mirrorly in 3.0?

Tags: weight-painting

[image]
In this setting, nothing special happens after painting.

[image]
In this setting, weight is painted symmeticaly but on a same bone.

[image]
In this setting, weight is painted on symmetic bone concurrently, but on same place of mesh.

Comment: it should work, could you please share the object that you try to paint? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: I uploaded it onto OneDrive: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AkUvAiWJaUWkiNUbLN3JuZinMKxcYA?e=oTr6MC @moonboots

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mesh is probably not symmetrical anymore. If I symmetrize it again (select all in *Edit* mode then header menu > *Mesh > Symmetrize*) then weight paint, it works fine:

[image]